# woocommerce get order details after checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get, orders

I need to get the following information after checkout:

- order ID
- order date
- customer name (F/L)
- customer phone
- customer email

Which will be put into the session array and then stored in a seperate database.  Currently in my theme's functions.php file I have the following:

```
    //get completed order data:
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function' );
    function my_function($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['order_number'] = $order->[what would I use here?];
    $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['order_date'] = $order->[what would I use here?];
    $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['f_name'] = $order->[what would I use here?];
    $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['l_name'] = $order->[what would I use here?];
    $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['phone'] = $order->[what would I use here?];
    $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['email'] = $order->[what would I use here?];

    //for testing:
    $kioskDataFile = './testFile.txt';
    $kioskData = "kioskID: ".$_SESSION['kiosk_data']['kioskID']."\n";
    $kioskData.= "order date: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->order_date;
    $kioskData.= "\n";
    $kioskData.= "order ID: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->id;
    $kioskData.= "\n";
    $kioskData.= "order key: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->order_key;
    $kioskData.= "\n";
    $kioskData.= "first name: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->billing_first_name;
    $kioskData.= "\n";
    $kioskData.= "last name: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->billing_last_name;
    $kioskData.= "\n";
    $kioskData.= "phone: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->billing_phone;
    $kioskData.= "\n";
    $kioskData.= "email: ";
    $kioskData.= $order->billing_email;
    $kioskData.= "\n\n\n";

    file_put_contents($kioskDataFile, $kioskData, FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Being very new to WP/woocommerce I'm really not sure how to go about capturing this data (tried several google searches to no avail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by changing the code as follows and removing the 'add_action' component and function, and moved it to the "thankyou.php" page under child theme/woocommerce/checkout.

```
    $kioskDataFile = './logs/kiosk_log';

    $kioskData['description'] = "kiosk site - thankyou.php";
    $kioskData['kiosk_id'] = $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['kioskID'];
    $kioskData['order_date'] = $order->order_date;
    $kioskData['month'] = date("m");
    $kioskData['year'] = date("Y");
    $kioskData['order_number'] = $order->get_order_number();
    $kioskData['order_id'] = $order->id;
    $kioskData['order_key'] = $order->order_key;
    $kioskData['first_name'] = $order->billing_first_name;
    $kioskData['last_name'] = $order->billing_last_name;
    $kioskData['phone'] = $order->billing_phone;
    $kioskData['email'] = $order->billing_email;

    $s_kioskData = serialize($kioskData);
    $s_kioskData.= "\n";
    file_put_contents($kioskDataFile, $s_kioskData, FILE_APPEND);
```

I've serialized the array data so I can load it into an array via file() from the log file and sort/parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can var_dump the order and check what fields you get in order.

```
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function' ,10,1);
        function my_function($order_id) {
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );   
        $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['order_number'] = $order->id;
        $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['order_date'] = $order->order_date;
        $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['f_name'] = $order->billing_first_name;
        $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['l_name'] = $order->billing_last_name;
        $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['phone'] = $order->billing_email;
        $_SESSION['kiosk_data']['email'] = $order->billing_phone;
        }
```

You can get the list of properties from [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html) which you can get from WC_Order object.

Comment: Still doesn't appear to be working.   I even tried writing contents to a file and still nothing appearing(see edit in original post).